# Sails JS new response in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, sails.js, response, webstorm

I'm newbie in Sails JS..
I'm trying to create a new custom response, I didn't find any auto-generator so I created it manually.

```
//someName.js    
module.exports = function someName(data, options) {
    console.log('test');
};
```

I'm trying to access this response from controller:

```
//someController.js
module.exports = {
    someController: function(req, res) {
        res.someName();
    }
}
```

The problem is that WebStorm isn't recognize this response..

> Unresolved function or method someName.

But when executing the app-it's working..(WebStorm recognize the default responses which came with the 'sails new someApp').

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where did you define your `someName` response?

Comment: you don't need to-sails js do it for you automatically

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem with the latest Webstorm.

Comment: @mouche, I think the best will be to create an Enum and refrence the variable using JSDoc to that Enum.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the Sails.js library that loads custom responses probably does something like this:

```
files = getFilesInApiResponsesDirectory()
files.forEach(function(file) {
  name = extractName(file);
  res[name] = require(file); // <-- too dynamic to infer at this point
})
```

There is no way that WebStorm code analyzer could infer the relationship between `res` and your custom response function without actually running Sails.js code or receiving a (less dynamic, more explicit) hint.

Anyway, the message you got does not necessarily represent a critical error, it's a *"code inspection"* you can [disable](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html) or [suppress](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/suppressing-inspections.html).

Comment: I know I can, but I can't 'go to deceleration', and also it not auto-complete me with functions inside this response. Of course-the default responses working great

Comment: If your question is: "How can WebStorm go to my function declaration", my answer is "it can not", for the reasons I gave before.

Comment: So why it can with the defaults responses?

Comment: Because there are explicit references: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/dfaba709ebfb5fcd7669dc5b16eee643b6a29f94/lib/hooks/responses/index.js#L91-L97

Comment: Got it! anywhere-there's any workaround to make it work?